# How do I use the last N elements of a vector as a function parameters in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have been reading this website for quite a while now but have just registered.
I have also used search which did not seem to be very helpful.

Here it is:
As I am having fun with C++ I come along "lazy evaluation" conception on the Internet. I am interested in creating something like a "lazy vector" which is defined with the function which takes N arguments and first N vector elements.

However, I have currently come across the issue with it. Let me point it out:

```
template<typename T, typename... A>
class llazy
{

public:
    llazy(const std::function<T(A...)>& func, A... args) : func(func), vec({args...}), numArgs(sizeof...(args))
    {}
    const T& operator[](size_t index)
    {
        unsigned short tmp = 1;
        //Here I want to stray from 2 elements to pass to function and make the number at least like 0-4
        std::vector<size_t> v;
        for (unsigned short i = 0; i < numArgs; i++)
            v.emplace_back(vec.size() - tmp++);
        //As you can see here, there are no issues(if the vector has enough elements ofc) with these two
        unsigned long long i = vec.size() - 2, j = vec.size() - 1;
        while (vec.size() < index + 1)
            //So how do I pass all the vec[v[0]], vec[v[1]], etc... elements to the "func"?
            //Maybe there is another way to achieve this, however, this is the Python which makes me think this is possible
            vec.emplace_back(func(vec[i++], vec[j++]));
        if (vec.size() >= index + 1)
            return vec[index];
    }
private:
    const unsigned char numArgs;
    const std::function<T(A...)> func;
        std::vector<T> vec;
    };

using ullong = unsigned long long;

int main()
{
    llazy<ullong, ullong, ullong> l(std::function<ullong(ullong, ullong)>([](ullong i, ullong j) { return i + j; }), 1, 1);
    l[20];
    l[50];
    l[1000];
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your answers in advance.

UPD: Sure, the vector can be passed to the function, however, this makes the functions themselves a lot less readable(e.g. unsigned sum(unsigned, unsigned) is much more clear than unsigned sum(std::vector)).

Comment: So, you have N arguments, you want to apply a function to each of those N arguments (or multiple arguments if the function takes more than one argument), but you only want to do so when it is actually needed?

Comment: @NathanOliver  I am sorry if the question has not been specific enough. As I am testing this I use the function to compute Fibonacci sequence –> it takes [0] and [1] elements and appends their sum to the vector. The same happens to [1] and [2], etc...
As for the computation – it indeed needs to be held only when the element is required to be in the vector(is called with operator[])

Comment: The title of your question seems very [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)-y to me. The *actual* question seems to be "how to use the last N elements of a vector as a function parameters", which doesn't necessarily involve creating a temporary vector to hold them.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  Thank you for correcting me, I have updated the question title with your suggestion. Your help with the forum concepts is really appreciated

Comment: I've also posted an answer, but it uses C++14 `std::index_sequence`. Are you ok with a solution that doesn't work in C++11 (which you tagged)?

Comment: In response to adding C++14 tag: So you seem to be ok with C++14. If the answer below worked for you, you should press the green tick at the left to mark your problem as solved. If you're not satisfied with answer, tell us what's wrong so we can improve it.

Comment: To avoid confusion, in future I'd suggest to not use version-specific tags at all, unless you specifically ask about a feature of that version, OR if you have to use an outdated C++ standard (in which case, I'd also say that in the question itself). *"Your help with the forum concepts is really appreciated"* I'm not sure if the comment is genuine or slightly snide. :) If latter, sorry if that came across as rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I use the last N elements of a vector as a function parameters

You don't need to put those elements into a temporary vector.

Instead, the classical solution to that is to use a separate function (or a C++20 template lambda, if you feel fancy) with a `std::index_sequence` parameter (and a parameter pack of indices). With a pack expansion, you can easily extract last N elements from your vector, one way or another.

Something like this would work:

```
template <typename F, std::size_t ...I>
auto make_tuple_seq(std::index_sequence<I...>, F &&func)
{
    return std::tuple{func(I)...};
}

int main()
{
    std::vector v = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    const int n = 3;
    auto t = make_tuple_seq(std::make_index_sequence<n>{}, 
                            [&](std::size_t i) {return v[v.size() - n + i];});

    // Prints `456`.
    std::cout << std::apply([](int x, int y, int z){return x*100 + y*10 + z;}, t) << '\n';
}
```

It shouldn't be hard to adapt this code for your needs.

Comment: According to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/ VS2017 does have apply...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Really sorry for that, messed up the configuration after x64 development. I feel guilty and stupid about it right now. The question can now be considered answered. A ton of thanks to you!

Comment: You're welcome. Also, I forgot that `apply` was from C++17 and initially told you it was C++14. :/